# Distinguish between substructure, submodel, elementary substructure, and elementary submodel.

Tags: logic, model-theory

I can see (although I must not really understand) the definition of these terms, but could someone please explain the difference between these concepts, and whether any one of them imply the other? Furthermore, does elementary equivalence imply isomorphism, or the otherway around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the exact difference between 'model' and 'structure', since it is used sometimes as synonym. I will refer the explanation [mentioned in Wikipeda.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructure#Submodel)

The term 'model' means a structure satisfying the theory $T$ (explicitly mentioned or not). From this we can infer the meaning of the term 'submodel': it means a substructure satisfying $T$ of a model of $T$.

I will give a example: imagine the theory of fields over the language $\mathcal{L}=\langle 0,1,+,\cdot\rangle$. The structure of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is a field. That is, $\Bbb{R}$ is a model of theory of fields. You are also noticed that structures of all integers $\Bbb{Z}$ is a substructure of $\Bbb{R}$, but it is not a *field* so $\Bbb{Z}$ is *not* a submodel of $\Bbb{R}$.
According to above definition and example, submodels are substructures, but the converse is not true.

The term *elementary substructure* is a substructure having same formulas true over the substructure with original structure. To be formal, if $\mathfrak{B}$ is a substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ then we call $\mathfrak{B}$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathfrak{A}$ if for each formula $\phi(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ with $n$ variables and for each $a_1,\cdots,a_n\in \mathfrak{B}$, we have
$$\mathfrak{A}\models \phi(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\iff \mathfrak{B}\models \phi(a_1,\cdots,a_n).$$

Trivially, elementary substructure is a substructure. Also, it is known that $(\Bbb{Q},<)$ is a elementary substructure of $(\Bbb{R},<)$. However they are not isomorphic.

Lastly, the term 'elementary submodel' is a synonym of 'elementary substructure', since if a structure satisfies some theory $T$, then its elementary substructure also satisfies $T$.

Comment: Is it a necessary condition that elementary substructures satisfy the same existential sentences as the original structure? If not is there a theorem whereby you can "complete" a substructure this way?

Comment: Additionally, when you say "the term 'submodel': it means a substructure satisfying T of a model of T." Isn't that the same as saying "elementary substructure is a substructure having same formulas true over the substructure with original structure". But submodel and elementary substructure are not the same concepts right?

Comment: @chibro2 Yes. Elementary structure satisfies *all* sentences which is true over original structure.

Comment: @chibro2 Every substructure is a submodel, but other directon does not hold. Remember the definition of a model: it refers both *structure* and *theory*, not a structure only, and if a structure is a model, then a structure satisfies given theory. (I think the sentence '$\mathfrak{A}$ is a model of $T$' describes the situation well.)

Comment: @chibro2: In general, there is no canonical way of "completing" a substructure to an elementary substructure. Skolem's theorem tells us that every set can be enriched to become an elementary substructure that is not much larger, but this is by no means canonical. In some cases, however, it can be made canonical. For instance, for algebraically closed fields (more generally, strongly minimal theories), algebraic closure is just what you need.